# C# Http Post receive json from body

Tags: c#, json, http-post

I have this HttpPost method:

```
[HttpPost]    
public string Test([FromBody]List<Account> accounts)
{
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts);
   Console.Write("success");
   return json;
}
```

and this is my Account class:

```
public class Account
{
    public int accountId;
    public string accountName;
    public string createdOn;
    public string registrationNumber;
}
```

This is my json file which i send with postman:

```
{
    "Account": [
    {
        "accountId": "1",
        "accountName": "A purple door",
        "createdOn": "25-07-2017",
        "registrationNumber": "purple"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "2",
        "accountName": "A red door",
        "createdOn": "26-07-2017",
        "registrationNumber": "red"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "3",
        "accountName": "A green door",
        "createdOn": "27-07-2017",
        "registrationNumber": "green"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "4",
        "accountName": "A yellow door",
        "createdOn": "25-07-2017",
        "registrationNumber": "yellow"
    }
    ]
}
```

If i send this json my method doesn't work and it returns a null object.
The only way to make it work is by sending the object only without the "Account" like this:

```
[
    {
      "accountId": "1",
      "accountName": "A purple door",
      "createdOn": "25-07-2017",
      "registrationNumber": "purple"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "2",
      "accountName": "A red door",
      "createdOn": "26-07-2017",
      "registrationNumber": "red"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "3",
      "accountName": "A green door",
      "createdOn": "27-07-2017",
      "registrationNumber": "green"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "4",
      "accountName": "A yellow door",
      "createdOn": "25-07-2017",
      "registrationNumber": "yellow"
    }
]
```

But i want the previous file format.
How could my method receive the previous JSON ?

Comment: Create a complex type property in new class with the type of Account.

Comment: Type of parameter you are trying to deserialize does not correspond to the structure stored in JSON. You can use something like http://json2csharp.com/ to check what the correct C# type would look like.

Comment: Well i have already tried to make another class which contains a list of my Account class but although it returned the correct number of accounts , each of them had null members.

Comment: Try to add as property {get;set;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this contract to achieve your requirement.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Account[] Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string accountName { get; set; }
    public string createdOn { get; set; }
    public string registrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Method should be like this.

```
[HttpPost]    
public string Test([FromBody]Rootobject accounts)
{
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts);
   Console.Write("success");
   return json;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...!! My bad was that i was making a list of Account in the Rootobject rather than an Array.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper for you class Account  and change the method defination

```
public class Account
        {
            public int accountId;
            public string accountName;
            public string createdOn;
            public string registrationNumber;
        }
        public class AccountWrapper
        {
            public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        }
public string Test([FromBody]AccountWrapper accounts)
    {

    }
```